# SourceTree does not fully uninstall

Tags: windows, atlassian-sourcetree

Using SourceTree on windows. I would like to do a full uninstall to re-install. However, I uninstall and delete remaining registry info, on re-install SourceTree skips all of the setup and just opens like it never left. I don't even have to re-login or anything.

Wondering if anyone has experienced this and can help me solve it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue, attempting uninstall would simply remove SourceTree from the list of programs in the "Uninstall or Change a Program" menu.

I ended up removing all SourceTree files from `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Atlassian` in addition to the `SourceTree` and `SourceTree-settings` folder from the `Local` folder. I backed them up to my desktop just in case, but obviously you can delete these after if it is successful.

After that, the next install prompted regular setup.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the steps here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/how-to-wipe-sourcetree-preferences-412484640.html

> Windows
>
> - Make sure SourceTree is closed
> - Make sure the files are backed up in the following folders before removing the files
> - Remove files "bookmarks.xml", "opentabs.xml", "userhosts" in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\`
> - Remove file in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe<random_string>\<version_number>\user.config`
> - Open SourceTree again to test if it worked or not.

Comment: this link is dead - https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/how-to-wipe-sourcetree-preferences-412484640.html

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree
```

Delete this folder and reinstall the sourcetree.

If you didn't find AppData folder inside users, click view in top menu and check "**Hidden Items**". Then hidden items will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Completely Uninstall SourceTree from windows...

```
1) Uninstall sourcetree by going in control panel/ uninstall a program and click    
   on sourcetree or above a option named uninstall.
2) Navigate to
```

> C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Local

```
  and delete SourceTree folder(if any).
3)Navigate to
```

> C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Local\Atlassian

```
  and delete all SourceTree folders.
4) Navigate to
```

> C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Atlassian

```
 and delete SourceTree* folder
    
-- Download SourceTree and install it.
```